# Can colors and shape be changed on a combined line and point plot while maintaining one legend per graph?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, legend, shapes

Using the following data frame:

```
day <- gl(8,1,48,labels=c("Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat","Sun","Avg"))
day <- factor(day, level=c("Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat","Sun","Avg"))
month<-gl(3,8,48,labels=c("Jan","Mar","Apr"))
month<-factor(month,level=c("Jan","Mar","Apr"))

snow<-gl(2,24,48,labels=c("Y","N"))
snow<-factor(snow,levels=c("Y","N"))
count <-c(.94,.95,.96,.98,.93,.94,.99,.9557143,.82,.84,.83,.86,.91,.89,.93,.8685714,1.07,.99,.86,1.03,.81,.92,.88,.9371429,.94,.95,.96,.98,.93,.94,.99,.9557143,.82,.84,.83,.86,.91,.89,.93,.8685714,1.07,.99,.86,1.03,.81,.92,.88,.9371429)
d <- data.frame(day=day,count=count,month=month,snow=snow)
```

I'd like to change the colors and shapes of the lines and points grouped by month on the following graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(data=d[d$day=="Avg",],aes(x=day, y=count, fill=month,group=month,label=month),show_guide=F)+
facet_wrap(~snow,ncol=1,scales="free")+
geom_line(data=d[d$day!="Avg",],aes(x=day, y=count, group=month, colour=month), show_guide=F)+
scale_x_discrete(limits=levels(d$day))+
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+
geom_point(aes(colour = month),size = 4,position=position_dodge(width=1.2))+
expand_limits(y=0)
```

[image]

1. **How can I change the colors and shapes (I realize that many options exist) of both the line graph and the points so that they are still grouped by month?**

*NOTE: A single legend per graph with the appropriate shape/color is desired (bonus points if you can figure out how to create a legend for each graph without using grid.arrange).*

Comment: I don't understand. Do the `scale_colour_*` functions not work for you? And have you tried simply setting the `shape` aesthetic, like any other? And why would you want two legends? The legends would be identical.

Comment: My actual dataset has over 27 graphs; thus, one legend for the entire set makes it hard to read.  Furthermore, try actually using scale_colour_* and the shape asthetic to see what happens.  You'll see why I have a question.  The colors/shape change the individual points or the lines, but not both simultaneously.  The month's color/shape should be the same for both the point and line. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: This still makes no sense. You _should_ be using the colour aesthetic, but instead you seem to be using `fill`. If you fix that, then `scale_colour_*` should work just fine. And when I set the shape aesthetic the shape changes just fine. I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're confusing `shape` with `linetype`?

Comment: @joran feel free to share your exemplary code.  The legend issue would be superb to understand as well.  Thanks.

Comment: @simplyclimb Do you want to have two different scale_colour_* legends, one for the points and one for the lines? ie, So that there is one legend with specific colours for the lines and another legend with specific colours for the points?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, that sounds great as long as the colors are the same by month; however, say we did the following: all of the red lines (Jan) are set to be dashed, the points along these red lines are triangles, and then the red Avg point is also a triangle.  In this case, we'd only need a single legend describing red triangles as Jan, ect.  I'm trying to make the Jan line and point the same color while all of the points from the same month have the same shape allowing a single legend to describe the graph.  Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe @thunk has it right, but there's some more problems with your code. (1) You specify `fill`, but then you don't use any geoms that take a `fill`. (2) You set the default aesthetics in the first `ggplot`, then you needlessly reset them in your `geom`s. (3) You want the shapes to change, but you never specify a shape aesthetic.

I think this gives what you want:

```
ggplot(data=d[d$day=="Avg",],
       aes(x=day, y=count, color=month, group=month,
           label=month, shape = month), show_guide=F)+
    facet_wrap(~snow, ncol=1, scales="free")+
    geom_line(data=d[d$day!="Avg", ])+
    scale_x_discrete(limits=levels(d$day))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+
    geom_point(size = 4, position = position_dodge(width=1.2))+
    scale_color_manual(values = c("dodgerblue4", "firebrick4", "forestgreen")) +
    expand_limits(y=0)
```

[image: fixed plot]

In the first `aes` call in the initial `ggplot()` we specify that both `color` and `shape` vary by month. Then, in the `geom_line` and `geom_point` calls we don't need to say so again. Adding `scale_color_manual()` lets us pick whatever colors we want, (and if you want to specify shapes, adding `scale_shape_manual()` will work for that).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you want to do can be achieved by adding the following line to your graph creation:

```
+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("yellow","pink", "brown"))
```

Here you can chuck in whichever colours you want your lines and points to have. The same can be done with scale_shape_manual etc. Have a closer look at the docs:

http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_manual.html

But in general, I think that the graph you are producing does not necessarily portray the data you have in the most useful and accessible way. So maybe rethink what you actually want this graph to tell, and e.g. reconsider if connecting the days of the week with a line is helpful here, as the values are really averages for the weekdays and thus these averages are not really temporally connected in a linear order. And I also think that putting the average in the same graph (as if it were another day) adds some confusion. But then, I don't know the bigger picture...